# Linking to different versions of a library with cmake

Tags: ubuntu, linker, cmake, makefile, shared-libraries

When using cmake to link code to a library, I am trying to understand how Ubuntu finds the correct library when there may be more than one version installed.

For example, in my case, I have installed the library `libpng` by running `sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev`. This library is old, but I need to retain it for compatibility with an old project. However, another project of mine requires the updated version, `libpng16-dev`, which is only available as source code, not via `apt-get`. So, I downloaded the source, compiled and installed it locally.

What I am wondering now, is when I have `find_package(PNG)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, which version it will find?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/ctest2.6docs.html#command:find_package), if you do not specify the version, you leave it up to cmake to find the library.  For some libraries, such as the one you are using, this will cause problems.  For others, it might not in some circumstances.  It sounds to me like you should explicitly specify the version you need, as in:

```
find_package(<package> [version] ...)
```